# Postfix: Email Forwarding - Relay Access Denied

Tags: linux, postfix

I have a system that we've setup as a mailserver to forward all email that comes into it for that domain to other external email addresses.  I've been digging around and found [this tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-postfix-forward-email-to-another-account/) which I thought would be perfect as it did exactly what I want it to.

The problem that I'm getting is that it says **Relay access denied** when someone tries to send the domain emails.

**/var/log/maillog**

```
Oct 23 16:23:13 MXSERVER postfix/smtpd[2011]: connect from mail-io1-f48.google.com[209.85.166.48]
Oct 23 16:23:13 MXSERVER postfix/smtpd[2011]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-io1-f48.google.com[209.85.166.48]: 454 4.7.1 <phonic@testdomain.org>: Relay access denied; from=<phonic@gmail.com> to=<phonic@testdomain.org> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-io1-f48.google.com>
Oct 23 16:23:13 MXSERVER postfix/smtpd[2011]: disconnect from mail-io1-f48.google.com[209.85.166.48]
```

**/var/postfix/main.cf | grep -v "#"**

(Since there's a lot of commented out lines in main.cf I'm grepping them out to save room)

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = mail.testdomain.org
mydomain = testdomain.org
myorigin = testdomain.org
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/32, 127.0.0.0/8, localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
virtual_alias_domains = testdomain,org
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks
        permit_sasl_authenticated
        reject_unauth_destination
```

**/etc/postfix/virtual**

```
testdomain.org            dest
phonic@testdomain.org     phonic@destdomain.org
@testdomain.org           phonic@destdomain.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> virtual_alias_domains = testdomain,org

Shouldn't that be `testdomain.org` ?

Comment: Yes it is!  I just figured this out and tested that it's working fine.  You beat me to updating this questions.  Such a small typo had me stumped for a while.